# How do I make this code activate when a collision occurs?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This code is meant to trigger on a collision:

```
public class Collision : MonoBehaviour {

  public CustomClass myObject;

  void onCollisionEnter(Collision crash){
    myObject.Slowdown();
  }
  void Start () {}
  void Update () {}
}
```

I have attached it to the object (randomObject) that will collide with my main object (myObject), but it's not working.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: They are both rigidbodies and are definitly colliding: if randomObject falls on myObject, it stops moving and lies on it but when myObject moves it continues to fall.

Comment: Check if you have RigidBody on at least one object, that is going to collide and that both have attached colliders of some sort.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov Both are rigidbodies but only one has the script attached.

Comment: Is Kinematic option is turned of in both? Is Trigger is also turned off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class and the UnityEngine class that's a parameter to [`OnCollisionEnter`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html) are both named `Collision`.  If you change the name of your class to reduce confusion (my recommendation), or change the method declaration to the following, it should work:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(UnityEngine.Collision crash){
```

Comment: Damm that reflexion in Unity 3d for scripts ))

Comment: It still isn't working, even with the case changed. I have 'is Kinematic' turned on for 'myObject', but not 'randomObject'

Comment: @IlyaIvanov I tried, it didn't work. I also got a strange error that said 'Script error: OnCollisionEnter
This message parameter has to be of type: Collision
The message will be ignored.'

Comment: I've edited my answer to point out that your class is named the same thing as a UnityEngine class.  This name collision (no pun intended) is what's confusing you.